# Xcode 8 Pod update issue - Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, swift3

I installed the latest version Xcode 8 beta. My Project was developed by Swift 2.0. So I convert the project to Swift 3. So I update the pod file. But When I update the pod file I am getting error.

**Pod file:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod "SwiftSpinner"
#pod "AFNetworking", "2.5.0"
pod 'HanekeSwift'
```

**Error message:**

> Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update. Analyzing
>   dependencies [!] The dependency `Alamofire (~> 3.4)` is not used in
>   any concrete target. The dependency `SwiftyJSON (from`
>   https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)` is not used in any
>   concrete target. The dependency `SwiftSpinner` is not used in any
>   concrete target. The dependency `HanekeSwift` is not used in any
>   concrete target.

NOTE:
I already update the cocoapods using this command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: give target and in that specify your pods

Comment: This is due to a change in cocoapods, not Xcode 8

Comment: yes. Thanks @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: Yes. This is duplicate. Just now I found. Thanks

Comment: yes, Whenever you want to add new pod/ update exiting pod provide path where you want to install.

Comment: @BhumeshPurohit I agreed. But I can remember, previously without target name I update the pod file. It was worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To solve this issue delete the current pod file and create one using the terminal. Follow the below steps:

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate to your Project Path
3. Type `pod init` in terminal to create new pod file
4. Open the newly created pod file and write the pod line which you want to install after `target "TargetName" do` and before `end`.
5. Then type `pod install` in the terminal

Hope this helps!

Comment: @SathiReddy Thanks ;)